# How to tell if a button is pressed at a certain time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have a button with an image, and after a little while the button image will change, then change back after a few seconds. I want to be able to tell if the button is clicked while the image is different. thanks!

Comment: Access the image property.  "If the button's background image is X, do this, if it is Y, do that."

Comment: Or compare to the timer or whatever other state value you're using to control the image.

Comment: code? @Nerrolken i'm new and don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: Code -- right!!  You need to show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options, but I'll detail two of them.  The first is more self-contained and foolproof, but the second is arguably easier to read and understand.

### Check the background image

The easiest way to do this would probably be to just test against the image itself.  The image changes from time to time, but you don't really care *when* the button is pressed, you just care which background is visible when it is.

In other words, all you really need to know is whether the button's background is the MainBackground or the AlternateBackground, so when the button is pressed, you can simply check which one it is.

Try something like this, for when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    UIImage *mainBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR_IMAGE_NAME"];

    NSData *imgdata1 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(sender.image);
    NSData *imgdata2 = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mainBackground);

    if ([imgdata1 isEqualToData:imgdata2]) {
        // The button's background is the MainBackground, do one thing
    } else {
        // The button's background is the AlternateBackground, do another thing
    }
}
```

### Keep track of which image is currently displayed

Alternatively, you could have a BOOL value flip whenever the image's background is changed.  Something like...

```
@property BOOL isMainBackground;
```

...in your H file, and then whenever you set the button's background image, you also set `self.isMainBackground = YES;` or `self.isMainBackground = NO;`

Then, your method for the button press would look something like this:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {
    if (self.isMainBackground) {
        // The button's background is the MainBackground, do one thing
    } else {
        // The button's background is the AlternateBackground, do another thing
    }
}
```

Comment: worked great the first one did! thanks so much! i did have to change sender.image to sender.curentImage, but that is no big deal! thanks so much!